# How to pass the enter key press to command line from a java application

Tags: java, command-line, process

I am writing a java program which will run some installed tools on a Linux Ubuntu OS, I need to execute two consecutive commands in the same process but with making the first one execute completely and then call the second one. I have tried using "\n" to separate the two commands as in the following code, but It didn't work.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("spin");
    command.add("-p");
    command.add("-u100");
    command.add("D:\\promela\\peterson.pml");
    command.add("\n");
    command.add("cc -o pan pan.c");
    command.add("./pan");


    String[] commandArray = command.toArray(new String[command.size()]);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandArray);
    Process process;
    try {

          process = pb.start();

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
          BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
          String errline, outline;


          for(String s : command)
           {
             System.out.println(s + " ");
           }

           while ((outline = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
             System.out.println(outline);
           }

           while ((errline = errReader.readLine()) != null)
           {
              System.err.println(errline);
           }


    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoForberg No, how can I pass ctrl+enter from Java?

Comment: ah forget it. was wrong. Thought you needed to pass enter when reading from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done:

- Either you launch a terminal/console/bash process, in which you can "type" commands, or
- you launch a specific executable that can't parse those commands and it won't work.

Wouldn't it be easier to start 2 processes?

Side note: you should not read the out and err streams one after the other, you should read them in parallel in separate threads, or, easier, use [`ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28%29) so you only need to read from one stream (out).

Comment: This code will run on a server, so won't be able to type; It should be automated. Re. starting 2 processes, the two commands follow each other; the first generates some C code which then can be used for the second command .. Is there any other alternatives to do something like that?. Thanks for the side note.

Comment: @Sam By "type" I meant sending keys to the outputstream of the process from your java code. What prevents you from generating your c code in a process, wait until that process finishes (with `waitFor()`), then start a second process to execute your second command?

Comment: thanks .. If I am not getting it wrong, what I was trying is the first option in your answer. It might work to start another process, but I tried another fix which worked (Its probably similar to starting another process); and that is restructuring the way I represent commands so that I can recognize each individual one like `spin -p -u10 xyz.pml` and start the process several times, each with the new command